# Using .osm.pbf file as an offline map resource for QT OpenStreetMap plugin

Tags: openstreetmap, qt

I implemented the example in the link below,

https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qtlocation-using-offline-map-tiles-openstreetmap-plugin

Works well, however I need much more map data then the provided file in the example. To satisfy this absent I exported necessary map area in the format of .osm.pbf.

But I am not able to use this format in the QT plugin.

Comment: The plugin requires [*tiles*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), i.e. pre-rendered map images. `.osm.pbf` instead is *raw* data that needs to be [rendered](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) first, resulting in these tiles.

Comment: Are there any tool for rendering process?

Comment: Yes, see rendering link from my previous comment. Examples are [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive), [Kosmtik](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Kosmtik) and [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QtLocation plugin requires [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), i.e. pre-rendered map images. `.osm.pbf` instead is raw data that needs to be [rendered](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) first, resulting in these tiles. This means you either have to find an online resource for downloading OSM tiles or you have to render them yourself. For rendering take a look at [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive), [Kosmtik](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Kosmtik) or [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill).